# Where do I get the javax.servlet.http.annotation package from?

Tags: java, servlets

Here the code:

```
package de.swt1321.servlet;

import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.http.annotation.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.http.annotation.GET;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Servlet(urlMappings={"/ServletTest"})
public class ServletTest {
    private static final java.nio.charset.Charset UTF8 = java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF8");
    @GET
    public void handleGet(HttpServletRequest req,
                          HttpServletResponse res)
    {
        byte[] HTML = "<html><head><title>Hello World!</title></head><body><h1>IT WORKED!</h1></body></html>".getBytes(UTF8);
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        res.setHeader("content-type","text/html;charset=utf8");
        res.setIntHeader("content-length",HTML.length);
        OutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();
        os.write(HTML);
        os.flush();
    }
}
```

I'd expect this to work according to [this](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/14/introduction-to-servlet-3.html)
, unfortunately I've so far been unable to find a jar that contains the `javax.servlet.http.annotation` package. I looked in "javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0" from http://download.java.net/maven/2 as well as in the `servlet-api-3.0.jar` shipped with Jetty 9, but so far without luck. I'm kind of out of ideas here, what am I missing?

So far I'm building/attempting to build with this Buildr buildfile:

```
# Version number for this release
VERSION_NUMBER = "1.0.0"
# Group identifier for your projects
GROUP = "swt1321"
COPYRIGHT = ""

# Specify Maven 2.0 remote repositories here, like this:
repositories.remote << "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

# This really bugs me, this isn't only supposed to build on my own PC after all!
# But as I said, the one at the download.java.net repo didn't work
JAVA_EE_PATH = "/home/hannes/Lib/Java/jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3/lib/servlet-api-3.0.jar"
java_ee = artifact("de.swt1321:java_ee:jar:1.0").from(file JAVA_EE_PATH)

project_layout = Layout.new
project_layout[:source,:main,:java] = 'src'
project_layout[:source,:test,:java] = 'test'

desc "The Servlettest project"
define "ServletTest", :layout => project_layout do
  project.version = VERSION_NUMBER
  project.group = GROUP
  manifest["Implementation-Vendor"] = COPYRIGHT
  compile.with java_ee
  package :war
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to give a glance to a [more updated example](http://explodingjava.blogspot.com/2010/05/servlet-30-annotations.html) of the web servlet api

Nonetheless, if you are still looking for the libraries used by the 2008 example, I'd suggest you these ones according to [Jarvana](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/mortbay/jetty/servlet-annotation-spec/3.0.pre0/servlet-annotation-spec-3.0.pre0.jar!/javax/servlet/http/annotation/Servlet.class?classDetails=ok)

```
Maven:  

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-annotation-spec</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.pre0</version>
</dependency>
```

BONUS: your GET annotation seems to belong to [another package](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=class&java_class=javax.servlet.http.annotation.%2a)

Comment: In other words, that article I read was actually full of - excuse the expression - shit and I just wasted 3 hours of my life looking for a part of the servlet API that's not part of the servlet API?

Comment: @Cubic That's what happens when reading a four-year old article on a then-incomplete spec, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

this package is the sub package of servlet-api.jar and you can find this jar file in the container's lib folder. For tomcat it is 
**[tomcat installation directory]->lib->servlet-api.jar**

Comment: No it's not, at the very least not in Tomcat 7 or in Jetty 9 (afaik the newest versions of either). Seriously, does nobody check before answering?